# I can't appear the menu at left dashboard

Tags: wordpress

could any one can help me ? why my WordPress can not appear this add_menu? I don't know where i the mistake??
I dont know where i missed, any one could help me please ,thanks alot!

```
class Main_Menu{
        function __construct() {
           
         add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'wpdocs_add_page') );
    
        }
    
    
        function wpdocs_add_page() {
         
            add_menu_page(
                'Unsub List',
                'Unsub List2',
                'this is the description for the menu',
                'menu_url',
                'menu_page_callback',
                '',
                1
            );
        
           
        }
    
        function menu_page_callback() {
    
                    echo '<div> hello</div>';
                }
    
    
    }
    
    new Main_Menu();
```

Comment: Have to tried to take the function "wpdocs_add_page" out of this class ... ? Just putting the function in functions.php for example?

Comment: actually, i want have the formal form for those. I follow the guide, i copy their code without any error, but with me, it throw out error.